# How does a SHOW statement map to a query

Tags: mysql

In mysql, does a `SHOW SOMETHING` statement act as a shorthand to running a query on the information schema? For example, it seems like the following two are equivalent:

```
SHOW databases;
SELECT schema_name FROM schemata;
```

Is there a way to create a new user-defined `SHOW` statement, for example, something like `SHOW LOCKING QUERIES`, or is that not possible to do?

Comment: SHOW are hardcoded views. SHOW cannot be defined by user.

Comment: @Akina could you pease clarify a bit on this? For example if it were a view I could do `SELET * FROM (view) WHERE (subselect, multiple where clauses, join etc.) but seems like it just uses a different parser or something.

Comment: SHOW is a keyword which means that the next word is a name of system view. It is not SELECT. Its parser only distinguishes the name of view to be executed, and, if allowed for this definite view, parses its LIKE or WHERE clause. If you need a view which may be used as row source then use INFORMATION_SCHEMA table (which is view too - but this time you can look at its code with the usual SHOW CREATE TABLE) or a query to it.